# Chart.js legend long labels clipped

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart.js chart with a legend that has long labels and they get clipped, like this:

[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/eimrek/pen/yLQbNdX

I would prefer that the chart gets squeezed together as much as possible to make the labels fit. Is there any way to do this?

I tried with `options.layout.padding.right: 100`, but this doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the option `options.plugins.legend.maxWidth`, see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html)

You may set a large number, like `maxWidth: 1000`, but since it is [scriptable](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options), you may use a function to make sure you leave some width to the chart itself. For a `maxWidth` of 90% of the chart width, you may use

```js
{
    options: {
        // other options .....
        plugins: {
            // other plugins .....
            legend: {
                 // other legend options .....
                 maxWidth: ({chart}) => chart.width * 0.9
             }
        }
    }
}
```

[codepen fork](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/eYQWxKg?editors=0010)